# C# Question about passing delegates as parameters

Tags: c#, delegation

I have a question regarding delegates. So in the Threading class, there is a method called public Thread(ThreadStart start) this method takes in a parameter of ThreadStart which is a  void delegate defined by Microsoft. What I can't seem to wrap my head around is the fact if I pass a method inside the parameter of Thread(ThreadStart start) it doesn't give me an error which is great. But why is it when I try to pass a delegate inside this parameter that is not type ThreadStart it gives me an error. I understand the signature of this method takes a delegate of type ThreadStart but then why can I put any method in without an issue but forced to use a delegate of ThreadStart for it not to give me an error. But I can enter any method I want as long as it doesn't have a parameter. Sorry if this is a basic question when am doing the stuff I like to know why a certain thing does something otherwise it bugs me. My guess is that maybe when you define a parameter with a type of delegate. It will let you enter any method you want as long as it fits the delegate's signature. But when you pass a delegate inside a parameter that is a specific delegate it will want you to use the same delegate as the type?

Comment: It would help if you provided actual code examples of what does and doesn't produce the issue, generally on SO it's best to include a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Also note paragraphs are free on stackoverflow... Use as many line breaks as you like

Answer (score 0):

In general you can turn a parameterized method into a non parameterized signature call

Just do something like:

```
var myThread = new Thread(() => MethodWithParemeters(Parameter));
```

doing () => Foo() uses linq (I think) to create a new method that calls Foo

Comment: Looking at the question again I've got no idea if this answers your issue, If my interpretation of your question was way off base let me know

Comment: var myThread = new Thread(() => MethodWithParemeters(Parameter)); ok i understand this but why do i have to add the empty parenthesis " ()"=>MethodWithParemeters(Parameter));  "()" what is the meaning of this why is this here. If this is what my parameters are then why do i write the parameters when calling the method. Why do I have to have empty parameters like this (WhyIsThisHere)=>MethodWithParemeters(Parameter)); WHY not like this =>MethodWithParemeters(Parameter)) why do I have to add this in front when it has no use () Sorry for dumb questions. Is it just syntax.

Comment: because () => is the syntax for defining a linq method with no parameters, the alternative is doing something like    x => which defines a single parameter - it's just the syntax for linq

Comment: How do I pass a method that  has  2 parameter then. do i do this Thread t = new Thread(() => saysomething(4,6)); in linq

Comment: Correct, that's the whole idea

Answer (score 0):

When a delegate is defined it attaches the signature to the name. So for:

```
public delegate void ThreadStart();
```

So any ThreadStart delegate must have a matching signature. So a function with another signature can't be passed to anything expecting a ThreadStart delegate as the parameter.

Since you raised the issue. I suspect what your code is needing is the constructor:

```
Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart)
```

Where ParameterizedThreadStart is:

```
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(object obj);
```

And the object that you pass is your own class or structure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you are asking why Case 1 succeed, but case 3 does not compile:

```
    public delegate void MyDelegate1();
    public delegate void MyDelegate2();

    public void MyMethod() { }
    public void AcceptDelegate(MyDelegate1 md) { }

    public void Example()
    {
        AcceptDelegate(MyMethod); // Case 1: Works
        AcceptDelegate(() => {}); // Case 2: Also Works
        MyDelegate2 delegate2 = MyMethod;
        AcceptDelegate(delegate2); // Case 3: Fails, cannot convert delegate
        AcceptDelegate(new MyDelegate1(delegate2)); // Case 4: Works, since an explicit conversion was used
        AcceptDelegate(() => delegate2());// Case 5: Works
    }
```

The reason that case 3 fails is that the delegate types are different.

The reason that case 1 work is that the compiler uses the [overload resolution rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/overload-resolution) to find a method with name `MyMethod` and have a compatible signature to MyDelegate. I'm not knowledgeable enough about the compiler to cite the exact rules that applies in this specific case. The important thing is that `MyMethod` is not e delegate, it is a 'method group' that can resolve down to a specific method that can be converted to a delegate.

See [How to convert delegate to identical delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040475/how-to-convert-delegate-to-identical-delegate) for more additional info.